# JupyterHub access AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter, jupyterhub

I want to give access to JupyterHub users so they can use data in AWS S3. I would appreciate if anyone explain how to set up for this usage.

Also, I would prefer if there is a way to not to give AWS credentials to the JupyterHub users but they would be just allowed to have access to data in AWS S3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely need an `IAM user` configured with the right permissions to access  the S3 bucket you need (or if you need full rights on all S3 buckets, you could attach the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to your `IAM user`).

Then on `Jupyterhub` you would need to have the AWS CLI installed so that you could run the `aws configure` command, by which you'd be able to configure the credentials of this `IAM user` in the `.credentials` file for AWS on Jupyterhub.

Once this is all done, you could use either the `CLI` or the `boto3` library to interact with your S3 bucket from a Jupyterhub notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use S3 as a file system in JupyterNotebboks with this extension:
https://github.com/danielfrg/s3contents